# IOS: presentmodalviewcontroller release

Tags: ios, dealloc, presentmodalviewcontroller

I use this code ti open a viewcontroller

```
self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:self.secondViewController animated:YES];

[self.secondViewController release];
```

but if i use `[self.secondViewController release];` when I call this code second time it crash because

```
[FirstViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x18a890
```

if I don't use it, it it's all ok, but in this situation when can I dealloc my secondviewcontroller?
can you help me?

Comment: Trying `autoreleasing` secondViewController and see if you get the same error

Comment: the firstViewController seems to be the deallocated instance...not the secondViewController.. as you have it right now without ARC secondviewController would be leaking it seems, if you declared the property as retain...you gotta post a little bit more info i think..

Answer (score 0):

From your code (`self.secondViewController`), my understanding is that you have declared `secondViewController` as a variable in your .h file, and `@synthesize`'d it in your .m file. 
If that's right, I would rather do the followings

> ```
> if (self.secondViewController == nil)
>     self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
>
> [self presentModalViewController:self.secondViewController animated:YES];
> ```

and in your `- (void)dealloc` method, I would add `[self.secondViewController release];` and in `- (void)viewDidUnload` I would add `[self setSecondViewController:nil];`.

The above code is with the assumption that you are **not** using ARC.
If you are using ARC, I would revise my code as follows:

> ```
> // Do not declare secondViewController as a variable in your .h file
> // Instead, in storyboard, give it an identifier, e.g. secondViewController
> // and 
>
> SecondViewController *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
> [self presentModalViewController:svc animated:YES];
> svc = nil;
> ```